# Newton's law of cooling and mixing warm+ cold water (each of equal volume)

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to understand some of the dynamics in Stommel's two-box model of ocean circulation in a way that I can explain to someone without too intense of a calculus or physics background. I want to work toward helping students create a mathematical model, but I don't want to get bogged down too much in the details of the physics.

I understand that Newton's law of cooling can be used to understand how water can cool/warm to eventually match the ambient temperature. I am using this as a difference equation (not a differential equation) to make this idea of the rate of change accessible to individuals without a calculus background.

Is there a way to use Newton's law of cooling to simulate water of the same volume (but one warm one cold) mixing? I have found some tutorials online to find the resulting temperature once the liquids are mixed, but I am more interested in the dynamics (i.e., what happens over time). So, the idea of what the temperature of the water eventually levels out to isn't that helpful. Is there a comprehensible simulation that can help with this?

Alternatively, I am thinking about creating different tables/graphs showing how the rate of change in temperature of mixing fluids begins at a faster rate when the temperature difference is high (simulating how high temperature differences can impact the rate of flow). I just do not have these tables or data. Also, with thermohaline circulation, the salinity works against the temperature, but in the North Atlantic the deep water formation happens at the poles where it's less saline but colder water (which seems counterintuitive according to some models of thermohaline circulation...which can be confusing).